# MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED using Python with selenium and chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to capture a page that has a brightcove video, and for some reason, instead of the actual video, I get the above error (with a message: This video is either unavailable or not supported in this browser)

I am using the latest selenium version, and the latest chrome/chromedriver, but still with no luck.

If I use the same script with FF or Edge, it works just fine, so its not a matter of scripting.

Also, on my Chrome browser it also works .. so does the Selenium + Chrome combo has any settings that I need to turn on or something, in order to make this work ?